# Insert spatial data into a duckdb table from R

Tags: r, r-sf, duckdb

I would like to insert data containing a spatial geometry into a duckdb table that contains a geometry column, but I am receiving an error.

Create the table using duckdb command line `duckdb ~/duck.db`

```sql
install spatial;
load spatial;

create table test_spatial (
  id int primary key,
  loc geometry
);
```

Attempt to load spatial data from R into the table

```r
library(duckdb)
library(sf)

db <- dbConnect(duckdb(), ~/duck.db)

pts <- st_as_sf(tibble(id=0:3,x=10:13,y=20:23),coords=c('x','y'),crs=4326)
st_geometry(pts) <- 'loc'

dbExecute(db,'install spatial;')
dbExecute(db,'load spatial;')

dbAppendTable(db,'test_spatial',pts)
```

The last line gives me the following error:

`Error: rapi_execute: Failed to run query Error: Conversion Error: Unimplemented type for cast (DOUBLE[] -> GEOMETRY)`

Comment: this line `st_geometry(pts) <- 'loc'` gives an error. I think you need to change the geometry's column name before this step.